# Asynchronous tcpclient rsponses always contain the data from the previous response

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcpclient

I want to start my post of by explaining that I am in way over my head. I am a novice C# programmer and want to learn more about asynchronous TCP. I have a project that I am working on and have run into a snag.

The following code I have butchered together from various sources around the internet. I cant find the blog that had the sample I was using. I am also using some ideas I received from the MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
    TcpClient objClient;
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    bool blLoggedin = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupConnect();

    }

    private void SetupConnect()
    {
        objClient = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        IPAddress objHost = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.125.111");

        objClient.BeginConnect(objHost, 21, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), objClient);


    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult objResult)
    {
        NetworkStream objStream = objClient.GetStream();
        byte[] objBuffer = new byte[objClient.ReceiveBufferSize];

        objStream.BeginRead(objBuffer, 0, objBuffer.Length, ReadCallback, objBuffer);

    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult objResult)
    {
        NetworkStream objStream = objClient.GetStream();
        byte[] objBuffer = (byte[])objResult.AsyncState;

        objStream.EndRead(objResult);

        string strData = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(objBuffer, 0, objBuffer.Length);

        //my data handling methods go here, removed for simplicity

        objStream.BeginRead(objBuffer, 0, objBuffer.Length, ReadCallback, objBuffer);
    }


    private void Write(string strText)
    {
        NetworkStream objStream = objClient.GetStream();
        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( strText + "\r\n");
        objStream.BeginWrite(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length, new AsyncCallback(WriteCallback), objStream);
    }

    private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult objResult)
    {
        NetworkStream objStream = (NetworkStream)objResult.AsyncState;
        objStream.EndWrite(objResult);

    }


    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txbSend.Text != "")
        {
            Write(txbSend.Text);
        }
    }

}
```

When I break after I create strData, the value of string data always includes the data from the previous read (with the characters a bit askew).

Example output;

```
Enter Password:
```

using my write method, I key in the password, I get this returned from the read...

```
Lnther Password:
ogin OK
```

using my write method, I key in a command, I get this returned from the read...

```
Lnther Password:
ogin OK
Command return
```

As you can see, the response always contains the previous responses included with it. I would expect the response to only include the new lines being returned from the server. Am I incorrect? Do I need to clear a buffer?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question! I had to clear my buffer...

```
Array.Clear(objBuffer, 0, objBuffer.Length);
```

Here is the new method.

```
private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult objResult)
{
    NetworkStream objStream = objClient.GetStream();
    byte[] objBuffer = (byte[])objResult.AsyncState;

    objStream.EndRead(objResult);

    string strData = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(objBuffer, 0, objBuffer.Length);

    //my data handling methods go here, removed for simplicity

    //I had to clear my buffer!!
    Array.Clear(objBuffer, 0, objBuffer.Length);

    objStream.BeginRead(objBuffer, 0, objBuffer.Length, ReadCallback, objBuffer);
}
```